# Xamarin.Android Samsung Crashes on DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a UserHandler Singleton Class and I declared a variable like this

```
class UserHandler
{
  ...
  public DatePickerDialog dialog = null;
  ...
}
```

Then in my MainActivity.cs file

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Interop;
using Java.Lang;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using AlertDialog = Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog;
using Exception = System.Exception;
class MainActivity
{
  private readonly UserHandler U_Handler = UserHandler.GetInstance;
  ...
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
    ...
    U_Handler.dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this);
    ...
}
```

When I run it on my device (Oppo, Android 8.1.0), it works normally but when I tried it on other device (Samsung, Android 6.0.1), it crashes and upon debugging, it shows this

`**Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError:** 'no non-static method "Landroid/app/DatePickerDialog;.<init>(Landroid/content/Context;)V"'`

How to solve this?
Should I use 3rd party Libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the constructor `DatePickerDialog(Context context)` was added in `API level 24`,when you run it in `Samsung, Android 6.0.1`,it will throw the `Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError` exception.

You can make a judgment call and use the old API when the SDK version is less than 24, and use the new API when it is greater than 24.

The api you could look at [DatePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog#DatePickerDialog(android.content.Context,%20int))

Comment: oh, I see, I checked and it is really is added on API Level 24, Thank youu